# Can't get dynamic condition working for has_many :through (+ ownership)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

### Still looking for a solution (2/24/16)

My user model has a has_many :through relationship with groups. So users have many groups and groups have many users, but I also want to establish ownership of the group by one user, who can make the ultimate decisions.

The idea is user.groups is all of the groups that  a user belongs to, and user.managed_groups is all of the groups that a user owns/manages. If anyone knows a better way to structure this, help would be greatly appreciated!

The code below is the setup I have right now.

### UserGroup Model (Join table)

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

### Group Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :members, :through => :user_groups, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
  ...
```

### Group Migration

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false, :default => 0
      t.string :name, :null => false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :groups, :user_id
  end
end
```

### User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups
  has_many :managed_groups ,-> { where(groups: { user_id: @id }) },
                  through: :user_groups, class_name: "Group", source: :group, 
                  dependent: :destroy
 ...
```

### It just doesn't work....

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create :user
@group = FactoryGirl.create :group
@group.user_id = @user.id
@group.members << @user
@group.save
@user.reload
```

The result is that `@user.all_managed_groups` is completely EMPTY, but `@user.groups` is not.

### What I've also tried:

```
def all_managed_groups
  groups.where("groups.user_id = ?", id)
end

def all_managed_groups
  Group.find_by_user_id(id)
end

def all_managed_groups
  Group.where("groups.user_id = ?", id)
end
```

After executing the above test code, these all return an empty association proxy

### What DOES work, but is stupid

```
has_many :managed_groups, class_name: "Group",
                  dependent: :destroy
```

then append every new group created by a user to their managed_groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something along the lines of:

#### Group

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :memberships, as: :memberable
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

#### User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships, source: :memberable, source_type: "Group"
  ...
end
```

#### Polymorphic Association

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :memberable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

This also allows `Membership` to be flexible into the future if you need to allow user associated memberships with any other models.

Hope this helps!

#### Followup Edit

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managed_groups, foreign_key: "user_id", class: Group

  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

user = User.create(name: "David")
group = Group.create(user_id: user.id, name: "Dayton Ruby")
user.managed_groups => [#<Group id: 1, user_id: 1, name: "Dayton Ruby">]
user.groups => [] (I have not added this user to the UserGroup join table yet)

# adding user as a group member (separate from ownership)
user << groups 
user.groups => [#<Group id: 1, user_id: 1, name: "Dayton Ruby">]
```

If you are looking to require the owner be a member of a group (versus manually setting it), you could also look at adding a `role`, `admin`, etc field to your UserGroup join table. That would allow you to add logic to determine which group member can manage the group.

Hope that followup helped some.

Comment: Thanks! I just need some clarification how can I quickly access the groups that the user owns directly from an instance of the user model VS. accessing groups that the user is a part of, but does not own

Comment: The `groups` association on `User` would be all groups you are a member of. If you add another association like:

    `has_many :managed_groups, foreign_key: "user_id", class_name: "Group"`

That would give you just the groups you own.

Comment: that association actually just returns all of the groups using user_id as a key, it has the same effect as the normal groups through user_groups association. I need a way to return only the groups that have user_id = current_user.id

Comment: I tried the following but i don't get any results after just creating a group, adding the user to the group.members and then settings group.user_id to the user's id. `has_many :managed_groups ,-> { where(groups: { user_id: @id }) },
                      through: :user_groups, class_name: "Group", source: :group, 
                      dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Sorry you are having trouble. I just setup a new rails app with the associations similar to your example (using UserGroup instead of Membership). I posted an edit of the associations above - but this allows me to find all groups a user is a member of as well as all groups they are the owner of.